# how to extract the first 400 characters from a log message in CloudWatch

Tags: parsing, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

Cloud Watch log insight query looks like this:

```
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream, @log
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

This `@message` field could have up to 6000 characters while only the beginning 400 characters make sense.
How can I extract the beginning 400 characters?